# Javafx official Alert/Dialog touch events

Tags: javafx, dialog, javafx-8

I built an application to scan items in our inventory and do the annual counting... Works great, on the computer. The aim is to have it on one of our `surface 4 pro` and run around with the barcode scanner and input the quantities. Works fine

As the app runs locally (wifi coverage too poor), storing data in SQLite, I have methods to sync the MySQL server. Works fine! But...

As every app, everything is closed controlled, and I use the official Alert dialogs to display the different `confirmations/informations/errors`. They don't respond to touch events! If I use a mouse, I can nicely click the buttons, but impossible to click them by touching!

As an example of a dialog:

```
public void syncServer() {
    final Alert confirmation = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    confirmation.setTitle("Confirmation requise");
    confirmation.setHeaderText("Synchroniser avec le serveur");
    confirmation.setContentText("Voulez-vous envoyer les données au serveur? Attention, cette action remplacera l'entier des données distantes par vos données locales!!");
    confirmation.initOwner(getPrimaryStage());
    Optional<ButtonType> result = confirmation.showAndWait();
    if (result.isPresent() && result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
        if (Mysql.getInstance().init(this)) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This alert typically shows a dialog of type confirmation with two button, OK and cancel. None of them react to touch events...

Anybody already had that and could solve it?

Looking a bit further on Stackoverflow, well, 2 questions about it, one using custom dialogs and adding listeners to custom buttons... It's a bit of a hassle to implement custom buttons for each and every dialog in the app...

Comment: You really need to create one custom `Dialog`. Then use it over and over again in the place of every `Alert`.

Comment: `Alerts` react to touch on my PC.

Comment: Hmm, it's totally weird. Sometimes it works, sometimes not. Usually if more than one button then not. I have no problem on my computer using a mouse, or one the suface with the keyboard connected and using the mouse. But when trying to touch, no chance for some reason

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32773115/javafx-show-dialogue-after-thread-task-is-completed

Comment: Are you calling the `Alerts` within a `Thread`?

Comment: Nope, on main thread