# Java FX new modal Window in Task

Tags: multithreading, javafx, modal-dialog, task, modal-window

My problem is that I can not start a new modal window in Task, it just does not go out. I do not understand how it is possible to derive not just an allert, but any modal window from Task. Translated by Google =)

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override 
            public Void call() throws ApiException,ClientException,InterruptedException {
                 int i = 0;
                 for ( i = 0; i < bufferLenght; i++){
                    try {
                    ...some code
                    }catch(ApiCaptchaException e) {
                       ...get capcha
                       captchaSid = e.getSid();
                       captchaImg = e.getImage();
                       System.out.println( captchaSid);
}

                    System.out.println(captchaSid);
                    if (captchaSid != null) {
                        System.out.println("gg");
                        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
                        alert.setTitle("Test Connection");
                        //here he is stuck
                        alert.setHeaderText("Results:");
                        alert.setContentText("Connect to the database successfully!");
                        alert.showAndWait();

                        System.out.println("gg3");  
                    if(i<bufferLenght-1) {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        };

        new Thread(task).start();
```

Comment: You cannot create a new window in a background thread. If you capture your exceptions with, for example, `task.setOnFailed(e -> task.getException().printStackTrace());` (before `new Thread(task).start()`), you will see the exception that is happening.

Comment: `Window`s need to be shown on the javafx application thread. Use `Platform.runLater` for this purpose. If you need to wait for the user to close the window on the task thread, `CountDownLatch` is your friend...

Comment: from ApiCaptchaException I get a link to CAPTCHA and I just wanted to open a window for captcha input and continue the Task execution, because in the TASK there is a method of queries to the API, I can not run it in the main FX Aplication Thread because I can not make many requests in 1 second and need a Thread.sleep.

Comment: I used Platform.runLater in Task for new window and this is worked, but when i entered captcha in window and then close it,my program stuck in Platform.runLater and my method which must accept capcha result in task not loaded.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/50067565/

Answer (score 1):

You must create and show new windows on the FX Application Thread. You can schedule code to execute on the FX Application Thread by submitting it to `Platform.runLater(...)`. If you need your background thread to wait for the user to dismiss the `Alert`, you can use a `CompletableFuture`, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50068002/2189127):

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {

        // ...

        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Test Connection");
            alert.setHeaderText("Results:");
            alert.setContentText("Connect to the database successfully!");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }, Platform::runLater).join();

        // ...
    }
};
```

If your alert is returning a value which you need, use `supplyAsync(...)` instead and return the value from the lambda expression. You can then assign that value to the result of `join()`:

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {

        // ...

        String result = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Test Connection");
            alert.setHeaderText("Results:");
            alert.setContentText("Connect to the database successfully!");
            alert.showAndWait();
            // presumably here you want to return a string
            // depending on the alert...
            return "" ;
        }, Platform::runLater).join();

        // ...
    }
};
```

Comment: I am a newbie, and lambda expression is new for me, can you write some example. my method must return a String

Comment: @fedotdeon There is very little difference, see update.

Comment: lol i thinking about this realisation, in this moment i read about lambda expression